# I need to rework this code so it includes everything that could read "inpatient" - including when misspelt?

Tags: regex, r

I either need to find a way of recoding this to include misspelt versions of inpatient or 'flagging' those that haven't been affected by this?

```
df1$Admission_Type <- as.character(df1$Admission_Type)
df1$Admission_Type[df1$Admission_Type == "Inpatient"]<-"ip"
df1$Admission_Type[df1$Admission_Type == "inpatient"]<-"ip"
df1$Admission_Type[df1$Admission_Type == "INPATIENT"]<-"ip"
```

It repeats like this.

Comment: `df$Admission_Type[grepl("inpatient", df1$Admission_Type, ignore.case=TRUE)] = "ip"` will cover the cases you listed. You can add checks for common misspellings as well, if you know what they are.

Comment: For misspellings, see `agrep`.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with case issues, convert all to lower case

```
df1 <- data.frame(Admission_Type = c("Inpatient", "inpatient", "INPATIENT", "inp", "impatient"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$Admission_Type <- tolower(df1$Admission_Type)
```

Then you can use regular expressions to deal with misspellings. While impossible to get all, you can use intuition to get close. In my example, I made the (intentional) misspelling of "impatient". You can set up a regular expression to detect this possibly common mistake as such

```
grep("^i[nm]pat[ie][ei]nt", df1$Admission_Type, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

where I allowed the second position to be either an 'n' or 'm', or the 'ie' to be switched at positions 6-7. This returns

```
[1] 1 2 3 5
```

You can add likely possible misspelled letters to each position. Plenty of tips on how to make this regex more complicated to allow for missing/extra letters if you search.

Note you can use `gsub` to do the replacement automatically.

Comment: all you need is `"^i[nm]patient"`

Comment: True, but was allowing for misspellings at additional positions. For example if i and e are frequently switched, [ie][ei]. `agrep` seems the better approach anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`df1$Admission_Type[grepl("inpatient", df1$Admission_Type, ignore.case=TRUE)] = "ip"` will cover the cases you listed. @JohnSG's answer shows how to include potential misspellings into the regular expression as well. (You'll probably want to create a new column to store your recodings (at least while you're testing out different options) rather than overwriting the original column of data.)

As @alistaire mentioned, you can use `agrep` for approximate matching. For example:

```
x = c("inpatient","Inpatient","Impatient","inpateint")

agrep("inpatient", x, max.dist=2, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

So, in your case, you could do:

```
df1$Admission_Type[agrep("inpatient", df1$aAdmisstion_Type, max.dist=2, ignore.case=TRUE)] = "ip"
```

`agrep` returns the indices of the matching values. `max.dist` controls how different the actual values can be from the target value and still be considered a match. You'll probably need to test and tweak this to capture mispellings while avoiding incorrect matches.

`grepl` covers the cases you listed in your questions, but for future reference, if you ever do need to match on a number of separate values, you can reduce the amount of code needed by using the `%in%` function. In your case, that would be:

```
df1$Admission_Type[df1$Admission_Type %in% c("Inpatient","inpatient","INPATIENT")]<-"ip"
```